# Printing mailing labels

Tags: java, printing, frameworks, mailing-list

I need to incorporate the printing of mailing labels in my web application.
The addresses are in a DB, and the function will allow the user to select addresses, then hit a button to print mailing labels.

Is there a Java framework for this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[JasperReports](http://jasperforge.org/projects/jasperreports) is an opensource reporting application.  There are mailing label templates [available](https://sites.google.com/site/jaspermaillabels/).

Comment: hi i have the same question but this template link is not working can you suggest me a way to print labels from java.